# Modprobe taking 100% CPU after kernel update

Tags: fedora, upgrade, cpu-usage, modprobe, nouveau

I'm running Fedora 36 workstation 
I did a dnf update and rebooted and now when I login modprobe takes 100% of my CPU, I couldn't investigate much further since my computer is thus unusable, opening a terminal and running top already took me 5 minutes and a reboot doesn't help

I know modprobe searches and installs kernel modules and their dependencies and I thus seem to understand why it could have a lot of work after a kernel update but it's been 3h30 now and it didn't even slowed down a bit

Any explanation or knowledge to share?

Edit: I logged out after 12h of this and noted that it doesn't happen if I login from a tty
Logging back in from gui leads to "only" 5-6 CPU cores being at 100% so I con now open Firefox, good start

Output of `sudo ps ax | grep modprobe` :

```
1594810 ?        R      0:01 /usr/sbin/modprobe -q -- char-major-195-255
1594823 ?        R      0:01 /usr/sbin/modprobe -q -- char-major-195-255
1594839 ?        R      0:00 /usr/sbin/modprobe -q -- char-major-195-255
1594857 ?        R      0:00 /usr/sbin/modprobe -q -- char-major-195-255
1594860 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto modprobe
```

`dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` repeats this indefinitely :

```
NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as: 
NVRM: nouveau, rivafb, nvidiafb or rivatv 
NVRM: was loaded and obtained ownership of the NVIDIA device(s).
NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
NVRM: again.
NVRM: No NVIDIA devices probed.
```

Ok it's much clearer now, but I don't really know what caused this, I can't recall having messed up with nouveau or nvidia drivers, I was about to but only downloaded the .run from nvidia's website

Comment: How long does it last or it keeps your CPU 100% busy infinitely?

Comment: It's been 12h now

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `sudo ps ax | grep modprobe` and `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn`. This command should finish near instantly. Have you tried rebooting BTW?

Comment: Edited, thanks
Yes, rebooting didn't help

Comment: Something is up with your NVIDIA GPU or/and drivers. What kind of device do you have? Desktop? Laptop with a discrete NVIDIA GPU/Optimus? Have you tried reinstalling/updating NVIDIA drivers if you actually use them? 195-255 is the driver responsible for `/dev/nvidiactl`.

Comment: It's a desktop with an optimus GPU (MX150). I blacklisted nouveau and rebuilt the kernel, it seemed to fix the problem. It's very strange since I never did actually install nvidia drivers but now lshw confirms they are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be a conflict between nouveau and nvidia drivers, my guess is that I forgot that I tried to install them before and that they only took effect thanks to the update. Blacklisting nouveau for modprobe and grub2 and rebuilding the kernel initramfs fixed the problem for me.